# FireBird - вставка нескольких строк одним запросом

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Можно ли в FireBird 2.5.4 использовать запрос, типа:

```
insert into SYNONYM (ID_EW1, ID_SYNONYM) values (33, 1), (44, 2)
```

на вставку одним запросом, несколько строк.
В отличии от других СУБД, он в FireBird, работать отказывается с ошибкой: "SQL error code = -104."

Спасибо
Этот вопрос дискутировался с interbase и FireBird давно, может за это время появилось что-то похожее, но в документации ничего подобного не нашел за исключением использования "UNION ALL"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html)

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SYNONYM (ID_EW1, ID_SYNONYM) VALUES (33, 1);
  INSERT INTO SYNONYM (ID_EW1, ID_SYNONYM) VALUES (44, 2);
  ...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, в FireBird так нельзя. И это не имеет особого смысла.
ИМХО, подобные конструкции нужны только СУБД где нельзя управлять транзакциями.